# How to find minimum first and last hour for each shift in Excel

Tags: excel, hour

I want to find first and last time for each shift of the day:

| Shift | Start Hour | End Hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Day Shift | 7:00 | 15:00 |
| Day Shift | 15:00 | 22:00 |
| Night Shift | 23:00 | 02:00 |
| Night Shift | 02:00 | 06:00 |

| Shift | First Hour | Last Hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Day Shift | 7:00 | 22:00 |
| Night Shift | 23:00 | 06:00 |

I have tried MIN and MAX array formula, it works on day shift because the last hour is always bigger (22:00), but at night shift, formula calculates 22:00 as biggest hour, not 6:00. We are using 24 hour format.

I am using 2019 Microsoft Excel
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How should Excel know that "2:00h" means the next day?

Comment: It shouldn't know. Below Tom gave a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2019 you should be able to use Minifs and Maxifs for the day shift:

```
=MINIFS(B2:B5,A2:A5,F2)
```

and

```
=MAXIFS(C2:C5,A2:A5,F2)
```

but as you say the night shift would need adjustment and you couldn't use Maxifs or Minifs because they don't work with arrays e.g.

```
=MOD(MIN(IF(A2:A5=F3,B2:B5+(B2:B5<0.5))),1)
```

and

```
=MOD(MAX(IF(A2:A5=F3,C2:C5+(C2:C5<0.5))),1)
```

[image]

0.5 is equivalent to half a day (12 hours) so I am assuming that if the night shift starts or ends before midday, it is into the next day so I will add 1 (a whole day or 24 hours) before finding the min or max, then take the result mod 1 to reduce it to a part of a day (i.e. a number of hours).

---

If there are blanks in the day shift, Maxifs will take care of them as it will ignore them.

If there are blanks in the night shift, try:

```
=MOD(MIN(IF(A2:A5=F3,IF(B2:B5<>"",B2:B5+(B2:B5<0.5)))),1)
```

and

```
=MOD(MAX(IF(A2:A5=F3,IF(C2:C5<>"",C2:C5+(C2:C5<0.5)))),1)
```

Comment: Hello Tom. Thank you for your answer. This solves most of the problem. If an entry is blank, it does not take the previous hour. Is there a way to this? 
For example, if you don't fill C5, then H3 shows 0:00, but not 06:00.

Comment: If I delete C5, it shows 02:00 in H3. What would you like to happen if the finish time is blank - would you like just to ignore it? What about the start time, can that be blank as well?

Comment: Ok, i've tested. Yes, if C4 is 02:00, H3 shows 02:00, it is correct. But if C4 is before midnight (23:00, 22:00 etc), H3 shows 00:00. Start time can be blank as well.

Comment: OK, will add to answer.